# Don't allow form to submit but instead send an xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I have this code below, just a simple event on form submit that send an xmlhttprequest

```
<form action="http://localhost/cn/account_test/index.php" method="post" onsubmit="login(this);">
    <label>Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

below is the login function that I bind unto the form on submit

```
    function login(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $data = [];

        $data.push({ username : this.querySelector('#username').val()});
        $data.push({ password : this.querySelector('#password').val()});

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", this.getAttribute('action'), true);
        xhttp.params($data);
        xhttp.send();

        return false;

    }
```

but neither from return false or e.preventDefault() is working. Any help, ideas please?

Comment: try `onsubmit="return login(this);"`

Comment: try <button type='button'>Submit</button>

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using inline JavaScript, you should setup an event listener using JavaScript.

**Step 1: Remove inline JS and add an ID to the form:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/cn/account_test/index.php" method="post" id="form">
```

**Step 2: Add Event Listener, fix incorrect XMLHttpRequest usage**

For example, `xhttp.params($data);` is not a valid function, rather, use:

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $data = [];

    $data.push({ username : document.getElementById('username').value });
    $data.push({ password : document.getElementById('password').value });

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", this.getAttribute('action'), true);
    xhttp.send($data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the form object, which doesn't have the `preventDefault` method. Pass `event` instead in the `login` function:

```
<form action="http://localhost/cn/account_test/index.php" method="post" onsubmit="login(event);">
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 *things* in your code:

1. The button `<button>Submit</button>` missed a type property:

`<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

2. `this` in the function `login(this)` doesn't have property `preventDefault`. It refers to `form` element.

You can try to set an id to the form and write an event listener like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", login);

function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('caught!');

    // more code goes here...
}
```

```html
<form action="http://localhost/cn/account_test/index.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <label>Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

ended using

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();

});
```

thx for the help, it works.